# Update web sphere MQ Queue Destinations using Jython script

Tags: websphere, jython, ibm-mq

How to update WebSphere MQ queue destinations using JYTHON script?

Currently we are using WebSphere Application Server version is ‘5’

Details are…

Name= ABC
JNDI Name= jms/ABC

Base Queue Name= X.Y.Z needs to be changed like X.P.Q

Please provide any sample Jython script details or any reference links related to that exactly?

Answer (score 0):

First, I don't think IBM introduced Jython until WebSphere version 5.1.  If you're running 5.0, you'll need to use JACL.

I don't have access to a version 5.1 WebSphere installation, so I can't verify my answer.  In your own installation look for AdminTask.modifyWMQQueue.  An excerpted wsadmin output from a version 7.0 install:

```
wsadmin>print AdminTask.help('modifyWMQQueue')
WASX8006I: Detailed help for command: modifyWMQQueue

Description: Modifies the properties of the WMQ Queue provided to the command.

*Target object: The WMQ Queue object to modify.

Arguments:
  ccsid - The coded character set identifier.
  ...
  qmgr - The queue manager on which the WMQ queue resides.
  queueName - The name of the WebSphere MQ queue that will be used to store 
              messages for the WMQ JMS queue type destination definition.
  ...
```

Be warned though.  In the past we have used Jython to manipulate data sources only to find out a recycle of the JVM is still necessary.  I can't say that we've tried this with MQ.